# SSRS/MDX - Needs to display all months

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I want to display all 12 months (January-December) in matrix. I'm passing one parametr `@year`. When I have all these months in cube, it's ok but if not - it doesn't display all months. What should I do, to have missing months and zeros in them?

Example:

```
@year = 2013  
jun | feb | ... | dec  
 19 |  3  | ... |  6
```

I have:

```
@year = 2014   
jun | feb 
 12 |  23
```

What I want to have:

```
@year = 2014   
jun | feb | mar | apr |...  
 12 |  23 |  0  |  0  |...
```

Thanks in advance,
Monica

Comment: I would try to add a dummy measure e.g. a count of days.

Comment: You need a calendar table, ie http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22776.t-sql-calendar-table.aspx.

Comment: What was the query you used?

Comment: Query? I had simple matrix table, where I had certain value, let's say `cost` and on columns I had `months`. Then I filtered data with `@year` parameter.

Comment: Reason I want the query is because it has got to do with the code, not with the SSRS. If you provide the query it would be possible to review it so that which could possible help you.